# Scripting issue in loadrunner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I have installed LR 11.5 in Windows XP Service Pack 3 machine.

I tried to record a web application but no events are being recorded and nothing can be seen in the script except the transactions given by us manually.

Then I tried by recording the usual search in  "[google.com]" through IE 8, but here the events were not generated during recording and nothing was recorded in the script.

Where might the problem lie? Why can't we record a simple google.com through LR 11.5 in IE 8?

[connecting through a "VPN"]

Comment: 95% of "I can't record" issues are related to a related to  failed installation.   if it worked before on this box, then look at your installation.  If it has never worked on this box then look at your environment and your installation.  Simplify.  Use the demo apps for confirmation, not a website where you do not have written permission to test.

Comment: Maybe this: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/LR-Support-Tip-Failure-to-record-encrypted-communication/m-p/6326607#M7856

Answer (score 0):

does the registry have the following key?

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows]
"AppInit_DLLs"="\bin\bbhook.dll"

Answer (score 0):

Check for Protocols of your web application.
First, run your web application through Protocol Advisor and select those protocol while creating a New Script.

Answer (score 0):

Before going to record a web application first you need to check whether the recording options are correct or not.

Note: After recording a business scenario, if events are not recorded then you can go to recording options then change port mapping capturing level to "Both like socket and wininet level".

Might as well regenerate events.